# How to compare the index of an array of strings to an array of another string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of strings that `$count_per_slot = [ "12", "9", "67", "120", "9", "67", "7" ]` and an array of which I will like to compare with the index of `$count_per_slot` so I can get the value of the index that is equal to `$index_to_compare`. The array of string to compare with is `$index_to_compare = [ "3", "4" ]` I was able to get the array of the index of `$count_per_slot` with the below code:

```
foreach($count_per_slot as $index => $row){

$index_of_count_per_slot = $row;

}
```

How do I compare `$index_of_count_per_slot` to `$index_to_compare` and any of the index that is true should return the value in `$count_per_slot`

Comment: Can't $index_to_compare just contain integers rather than strings. Then you can just use those as indices.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to get 3th and 4th values from a $count_per_slot array? In this case just use 3 and 4 as indexes: 

$result = []; foreach ($index_to_compare as $i) { $result[] = $count_per_slot[$i] ?? null; }
/* then exclude empty values: */
$result = array_filter($result);